# Is approving a edit for 2k users a bug or feature?

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits

A low rep user edited a question I was looking at, I thought the changes he made where good and I clicked to approve it. Now it is sitting waiting for a approval of a 2nd user.

If I had clicked "improve" and done no changes at all it would have let me apply the edit right away, I would have gotten credit for the edit instead of the low rep user, but there would have been no wait on the approvial.

Is clicking approve and requiring a 2nd users intervention to also approve if I am a 2k user a bug or a feature? And if it is "a feature" is the work around of "improving" the edit and changing nothing considered a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is clicking approve and requiring a 2nd users intervention to also approve if I am a 2k user a bug or a feature?

Yes, indeed. We require two reviewers to agree on a suggested edit. This is mostly to prevent users from blindly approving everything they see in the suggested edit queue—wouldn't be the first time this happened. It depends on the quality of edits and reviewers in general though: on Stack Overflow, three reviewers need to agree for an edit to be accepted or rejected.

> And if it is "a feature" is the work around of "improving" the edit and changing nothing considered a bug?

No, this is not a bug. Since you're improving the post, you'll actually have to make the edit yourself. You will be shown as the final editor of the post, only taking the suggested edit as a starting point. This makes you accountable for the edit as well, while the +2 reputation goes to the user who initially suggested the edit.

Comment: "Being responsible for the edit" makes seance to me, thanks for explaining it to me.

Comment: But wait @slhck, Scott has a point... what if the high-rep user goes directly to the question, clicks edit, makes changes unilaterally before approving the edit? they don't get rep obviously, but the edit will appear like they wrote it, and what would happen if 2 people approve the edit anyway and it has no changes vs. the latest revision (made unilaterally by the high rep user)? oh wait nevermind, answered myself, you can't edit a question unilaterally while there's a pending edit :P

Comment: @somequixotic: just a note: switch your `@` sign around, and put it with Scott, since slhck will get a notification *anyway* that a comment was put on this post. Thought, Scott is the OP, so it might not matter. Just an observation. Carry on! :)